# Is making the request object optional for a view incorrect in Django?

Tags: django, httprequest

Usually a Django view looks something like:

```
def exciting_possibilities(request, optional_variable=None...):
```

I have the case where the `optional_variable` is captured in the url via a regex. It's a user identifier, and only transmissible via GET as part of an email link due to specific business circumstances. If it's present, `my_view` dynamically chooses a "possibility". If it's not present, it renders an identifying form for the user to provide the info.

Let's say the user now POSTs the info to the form (simplified):

```
def identify_user(request):
    e = ExampleUser(identifier=request.POST.get("optional_variable", None))
    e.save()
```

Now that the user is identified, I want to now go back to `exciting_posibilites`, but obviously I can't just call:

```
return exciting_possibilities(optional_variable=e.identifier)
```

because there's no request (and generating one requires a URL, which I don't have).

Should I make `request` optional (with `=None`) and cut the "possibility choice" logic out into a separate function?

Or when returning from `identify_user` maybe should I pass the original request (even though it's a POST), and take the `request.method` checking logic out of `exciting_possibilites`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you do a redirect, from a POST view to a GET view. In this case, after form data is posted, just redirect to your `exciting_possibilities` view.

```
def identify_user(request):
    e = ExampleUser(identifier=request.POST.get("optional_variable", None))
    e.save()
    return redirect(reverse('exciting_possibilities', kwargs={'optional_variable': e.identifier}))
```